# Review indicator lits up, but no reviews are available

Tags: bug, review

Every once in a while, when I visit Retrocomputing, the red indicator over the review queue icon lits up.  However, when I pull down the menu, I see there are no pending reviews for me to perform:

[image: screenshot]

Sometimes the indicator goes away after refreshing the page, but hiding the menu does not make it disappear like it would with the achievements panel or or the inbox.

This is pretty distracting and I wish it stopped.  Why does it do that anyway?

Answer (score 4):

This is normal behaviour.  The indicator shows that there are reviews available for someone.

So, for example, if you 'skip' a review, it is still available but not for you.  Also, if you complete 20 reviews, there may be others available for others to review.

This is counter-intuitive but is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

This has been discussed on the main meta periodically, starting way back in 2014...
[Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/236563)

Comment: Interesting, I was always puzzled about that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, from historical observations on [Code Golf Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/): somebody's just quicker than you at starting reviews, so they're not available to review by the time you click the button.

This notification is designed for Stack Overflow, where there are a lot of users and it's expensive to calculate the number of available reviews, so it's probably a few seconds cached.